# How to get hex of asset colors?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to display a `WKWebView` using `loadHTMLString` that needs to adapt to the app's appearance. So I need the hex code of the current color in order to update the html and css of the webview. The problem is that I am unable to get the hex code for dark mode colors as it's not changing with the appearance.

Here is a sample to show the hex code of system colors. The UI behaves right. But the hex code is wrong.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ColorView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var body: some View {
        
        Text(colorScheme == .dark ? "In dark mode: " : "In light mode:")

        Text("background \(convertUIColorToHex(UIColor.systemBackground))")
        Text("label \(convertUIColorToHex(UIColor.label))")
        
        Text("Am in color shown above")
            .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
            .padding(20)
            .border(.red)
   
    }
}
 
func convertUIColorToHex(_ uiColor: UIColor) -> String {
    return convertUIColorToHex(Color(uiColor))
}

 func convertUIColorToHex(_ color: Color) -> String {
    if color == Color.clear { return "transparent" }

    var red: CGFloat = 0
    var green: CGFloat = 0
    var blue: CGFloat = 0
    var alpha: CGFloat = 0
    var myUIColor: UIColor = UIColor(color)
    myUIColor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
    
    let redInt = Int(red * 255)
    let greenInt = Int(green * 255)
    let blueInt = Int(blue * 255)
    
    let c = String(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", redInt, greenInt, blueInt)
    print("colortohex \(color) \(c)")
    return c
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not resolving the color with the current `UITraitCollection` so it won't get updated. To resolve it, use `resolvedColor(with: .current)`.

Also, I would make the root function take an `UIColor` instead of `Color` & make it extend `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {
    func hex() -> String {
        let resolvedColor = resolvedColor(with: .current)
        if resolvedColor == .clear { return "transparent" }

        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        resolvedColor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
        
        let redInt = Int(red * 255)
        let greenInt = Int(green * 255)
        let blueInt = Int(blue * 255)
        
        let c = String(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", redInt, greenInt, blueInt)
        print("colortohex \(resolvedColor) \(c)")
        return c
    }
}
```

Then extend `Color` to use the former:

```
extension Color {
    func hex() -> String {
        if self == .clear { return "transparent" }
        return UIColor(self).hex()
    }
}
```

Note: When you want to initialize `Color` from `UIColor` you need to pass the resolved color:

```
extension Color {
    init(uiColor: UIColor) {
        self.init(uiColor.resolvedColor(with: .current))
    }
}
//Usage:
print(Color(uiColor: .label).hex())
```

Comment: print(UIColor.label.hex(), Color(UIColor.label).hex())

lightmode log: #000000 #000000

darkmode log:  #FFFFFF #000000

which is strange. Should not both print the same value even in dark mode?

Comment: For that you need to resolve the `UIColor` when initializing `Color`. Updated my answer!

Comment: Now I need to allow opacity in hex calculations. Because my asset color has an opacity of 50% but its not reflecting in the hex calculations in the above code.

Comment: let alphaInt = Int(alpha * 255)
 
            let hexString = String(format: "#%02X%02X%02X%02X", redInt, greenInt, blueInt, alphaInt)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created Extension for UIColor using that you can get HexString.

```
extension UIColor {
        func hexStringFromColor() -> String? {
            var r:CGFloat = 0
            var g:CGFloat = 0
            var b:CGFloat = 0
            var a:CGFloat = 0
            
            getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
            let rgb:Int = (Int)(r*255)<<16 | (Int)(g*255)<<8 | (Int)(b*255)<<0
            return String(format:"#%06x", rgb)
        }
    }
```

Here I have created an Extension for String using that you can get UIColor from hex.

```
    extension String {
    func hexStringToUIColor () -> UIColor? {
        var cString:String = self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
        }
        if ((cString.count) != 6) {
            return UIColor.gray
        }
        var rgbValue:UInt64 = 0
        Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
}
```